# Evaluation of a valid FQDN on bash regex

Tags: regex, string, bash, if-statement, fqdn

**CORRECTED POST**

@stribizhev is right. You cannot use look-aheads in bash regex.
I used grep for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

fqdn=$1
result=`echo $fqdn | grep -P '(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?>(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'`
if [[ -z "$result" ]]
then
    echo "$fqdn is NOT a FQDN"
else
    echo "$fqdn is a FQDN"
fi
exit
```

Thanks to the help of @stribizhev and < +OnlineCop > and < tureba > at http://webchat.freenode.net/?nick=regex101 .

**ORIGINAL POST**

I am trying to make this regex work to evaluate if the string is or not a valid FQDN with no success. I went through various searches with no success too.

For example, I copied a regex find at 
http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1319
and tried this way but is not working. What can be wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

fqdn=$1
if [[ "$fqdn" =~ (?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?:(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$) ]]
then
        echo "$fqdn is a FQDN"
else
        echo "$fqdn is NOT a FQDN"
fi
exit
```

Comment: A FQDN is described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name .
"www.aa.com" will be a matching example. "xxx" will not match. "@#$#.com" will not match.

Comment: @stribizhev, I tried your example with no success. What would the if line be?
    `if [[ "$fqdn" =~ ^(?=.{1,254}$)(?:(?![0-9]+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$ ]]`

Comment: I think you cannot use look-aheads in bash regex. You will need another pattern. Or use Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one slight modification from the original, you can use `grep -P` instead of bash to accomplish this:

```
grep -P '(?=^.{1,254}$)(^(?>(?!\d+\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{1,63}\.?)+(?:[a-zA-Z]{2,})$)'
```

You can see the match [here](https://regex101.com/r/aN7jE7/1).

The difference, if you're interested, is to change `(^(?:(?!` to `(^(?>(?!` to prevent catastrophic backtracking.

zsh has support for a `-pcre-match` flag to be used within `[...]` and `[[...]]` as described on [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140694/which-regular-expression-methods-to-validate-input-could-be-used-in-shell-script) which may be a way to accomplish this if you wish to use another shell than bash, although bash scripts are not always compatible with zsh scripts.